# Keep remote session

Tags: macos, ssh

I am using Macbook developing a client application.

I want to access server logs, so I opened a shell terminal & established a ssh connection to the server & access the log file there by executing `tail -f server.log`

It works, but the remote ssh session will be expired after certain amount of time, which needs me to establish the ssh connection again & access the server log file again.

How can I keep the remote session all the time without expiration??

Comment: You might be better suited to ask this on, say, "super user" or perhaps "unix & linux", or even "ask different". You'd have to check their FAQs though to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) on your Mac in conjunction with [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the server.

If you use a package manager on your Mac you will probably find that they're packaged.

Answer (score 1):

One way of several to do this is to add the following line

```
   ServerAliveInterval 60
```

beneath the "Host *" stanza in the file /etc/ssh_config.

Since adding that line about a month ago, my ssh sessions have not timed out whilst tailing log files.

The file suggests looking at the ssh_config(5) man page for more information.

Here's my entire ssh_config file, with comments stripped out:

```
[mini-nevie:/etc] nevinwilliams% grep -v "^#" /etc/ssh_config




 Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*
   ServerAliveInterval 60

Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```